# HTML form fields are set but empty

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a normal HTML form which is submitted via POST. The submit works and also sends data to the receiver page. What confuses me the most, is, that the save-button and the hidden input (shop_id) are sent but not the selected options from the drop down.

The selects are in the post, but the values are empty. The post looks like this:

```
save:Speichern
data[58]:
data[60]:
data[61]:
shop_id:5
```

Does anyone know how this can happen?

```html
<form action="article.mapping.html" method="post">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1871px;">
      <colgroup>
         <col style="width: 268px;">
         <col style="width: 267px;">
         <col style="width: 266px;">
         <col style="width: 267px;">
         <col style="width: 804px;">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
         <tr class="size-row" style="height: 51.5px;">
            <th class="floatThead-col" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
            <th class="floatThead-col" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
            <th class="floatThead-col" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
            <th class="floatThead-col" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
            <th class="floatThead-col" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-center bg-info"><strong>Beck's</strong></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Beck's</td>
            <td>Gold</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>0.33</td>
            <td>
               <select name="data[58]" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Bitte wählen...">
                  <option value="">Bitte wählen...</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Alkoholfrei 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="">Beck's Gold Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Green Lemon Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Ice 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Gold 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck`s Green Lemon 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Red Ale 4-Pack 24x0.33l</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Beck's</td>
            <td>Green Lemon</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>0.33</td>
            <td>
               <select name="data[60]" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Bitte wählen...">
                  <option value="">Bitte wählen...</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Alkoholfrei 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Gold Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="">Beck's Green Lemon Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Ice 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Gold 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck`s Green Lemon 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Red Ale 4-Pack 24x0.33l</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Beck's</td>
            <td>Ice</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>0.33</td>
            <td>
               <select name="data[61]" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Bitte wählen...">
                  <option value="">Bitte wählen...</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Alkoholfrei 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Gold Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Green Lemon Sixpack 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="">Beck's Ice 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck's Gold 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Beck`s Green Lemon 24x0.33l</option>
                  <option value="">Becks Red Ale 4-Pack 24x0.33l</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save" value="Speichern"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="shop_id" value="5">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, although you provide the **text** to be displayed for the options, you don't provide the **values** of the options. The form is posted, but the values are simply empty because you set them to be empty.

An example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

```
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

To solve your problem, also fill the `value=""` attributes with the corresponding option values.

Comment: Yeah. I feel stupid now. Just saw it a second ago by myself. I was too focused on any other errors to see it. Thanks, mate

Comment: It happens to everyone all the time, no worries! :-)